# Change value in specific child element

Tags: python, elementtree

I have some issues with my script.

1. First of i wanna make sure that the correct **name** has been given by the user. For example if I were to write "Name" it should not match with anything in my xml. If i were to write "NameY" it should match with given name and not anything else(for example "NameX should not be matched). I tried using wordboundry but it did not help as I thought it would.
2. When I try want to change value in NameY the script changes for all the values(even for NameX). I believe this is because it can't seperate the "names"?

I am using argparse for this and the code is in another function.

- args.name = "the name to look for"
- args.dirname = "file location"
- args.value "the value I want to change to"

`wordboundry = re.compile(r'(<NAME>(%s\b)<\/NAME>)' % args.name)`

```
getName = ("{0}ROOTS/{0}ROOT/{0}ELEM/{0}SPEC/[{0}NAME]")
getDigit = ("{0}ROOTS/{0}ROOT/{0}ELEM/{0}SPEC/{0}DP/{0}NVP/[{0}CHECK]/[{0}DIGIT]")


for fileName in glob.glob(args.dirname):
    print fileName
    with open(fileName,"r") as file:
        my_files_content = file.read()

    if args.name in my_files_content: #instead of using args.name i was trying to use if re.search(wordboundry, my_files_content):
        print "Parameter exist in this file\n"
        tree = tree = ElementTree.ElementTree()
        tree.parse(fileName)
        ElementTree.register_namespace("", "http://something.com")
        namespace = "{http://something.com}"

        for names in tree.findall(getName.format(namespace)):
            mathcName = names.find('{http://something.com}NAME').text
            if mathcName == **args.paramName**:
                for digits in tree.findall(getDigit.format(namespace)):
                    digitNumber = digits.find('{http://something.com}DIGIT').text
                    convertToString = ' '.join([str(mystring) for mystring in args.value]) #Convert to string

                    digits.find('{http://something.com}DIGIT').text = convertToString #This allows the script to changes the digit in the xml file
                    tree.write("test.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
                    else: print"NO MATCHES\n"
            else:
                print "i am not here"
    else:
        "Parameter does not exist in this file\n"
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TOP xmlns="http://something.com">
  <ROOTS>
    <ROOT>
         <ELEM>
            <SPEC>
               <NAME>NameX</NAME>
               <DP>
                  <NVP>
                     <CHECK>NameX_1</CHECK>
                     <DIGIT>3</DIGIT>
                  </NVP>
                  <NVP>
                     <CHECK>NameX_2</CHECK>
                     <DIGIT>20</DIGIT>
                  </NVP>
               </DP>
            </SPEC>
            <SPEC>
               <NAME>NameY</NAME>
               <DP>
                  <NVP>
                     <CHECK>NameY</CHECK>
                     <DIGIT>7</DIGIT>
                  </NVP>
               </DP>
            </SPEC>
         </ELEM>
    </ROOT>
  </ROOTS>
</TOP>
```

**Edit** fixed the problem by changning "is not None" to "== args.paramName"