# Replace number in XML by using argparse

Tags: python, xml, argparse

Lets say I give the *arguments:* `python xyz.py --values [ 2 4 5 ]` from my terminal. I want to take these numbers and replace them in a XML file, how do I do that?

My XML file looks like this:

```
<DP>
  <NVP>
     <CHECK>NameX_1</CHECK>
     <DIGIT>3</DIGIT>
  </NVP>
  <NVP>
     <CHECK>NameX_2</CHECK>
     <DIGIT>20</DIGIT>
  </NVP>
  <NVP>
     <CHECK>NameX_2</CHECK>
     <DIGIT>100</DIGIT>
</DP>
```

When the user has given the arguments the numbers in that XML should be replaced. So `3 -> 2, 20 -> 4`, and `2 -> 5`.

```
for digits in tree.findall(getDigit.format(namespace)):
    matchCheck = digits.find('{http://something.com}CHECK').text 
        if matchCheck == mathcName:
            digitNumber = digits.find('{http://something.com}DIGIT').text
            convertToString = ' '.join([str(mystring) for mystring in args.value]) #Convert to string

            digits.find('{http://something.com}DIGIT').text = convertToString #This allows the script to changes the digit in the xml file
            tree.write("test.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
        else: print"NO MATCHES\n"
```

You can find rest of the code here: [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015120/change-value-in-specific-child-element])

Comment: where can we find rest of the code?

Comment: You are using namespaces like `{http://something.com}` - these won't match the XML sample you show because it doesn't have namespaces specified.

Comment: Err, your logic isn't right - think it should be: search for an NVP tag, then _within_ that tag confirm there is a CHECK and modify the DIGIT

Comment: Sorry forgot to paste the link for the rest of the code...

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015120/change-value-in-specific-child-element]

Comment: @barny I did not include the whole XML, this just a chunk of it. The XML has a root which contains the  "{http://something.com}"

Comment: You should post code and data (and also an executable example if at all possible) that is consistent otherwise viewers/potential answerers may well do what I'm now going to do which is not bother because there are probably other things you aren't saying that it just takes too much energy to dig out of you. Sigh. Good luck.

Comment: I linked to a previous question of mine which contains the full code and XML. I thought that would be better instead of writing everything again since there is not so much difference codewise.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether your question is about the `argparse` end of the code, or the `xml` end.

But if you define

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--values', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
values = args.values
print(values)
```

then calling (no brackets)

```
python xyz.py --values 2 4 5
```

should print

```
[2, 4, 5]
```

That is `values` will be a list of 3 numbers.  What you do with those three numbers is the responsibility of the `xml` editing part of your code.